# Why is having true beliefs important? (More detail)

Tags: epistemology, truth, belief

I forgot to keep track of my earlier asking of this question. Rather than make similar replies to many comments, I'll elaborate here. I'll use the example of panpsychism: it holds that natural laws such as physics predicts describe how the universe *works*, but not what it *is*, and it offers an answer: consciousness—or something. I have more to learn.

But Philip Goff claims every entity, even down to, say, electrons, has some level of awareness ("consciousness"), and that their predicable behavior creates the predictable laws of nature.

I don't see a way to dis/prove this, at least not right now. But I think it could be combined with a recognition that the macrostructure of the universe, which is said to resemble a brain, could suggest it has a "megamacroscopic consciousness" emergent from its subcomponents (like Boyle's gas laws emerge from aggregating descriptions of many molecules' behavior).

**I do not believe this!** It's an example I thought of that could give people a sense of meaning and purpose not intended by some god. In that sense, it could inspire good behavior (in utilitarian, virtue ethical, or whatever senses) by convincing people they're not "just" incredibly small organisms the universe doesn't care about.

Would there be harm in this? Pragmatically, since it doesn't contradict knowledge of how the universe *functions* like young Earth creationism, it seems like it could be harmless.

Also, is there a way for me to get notified via email when people comment on this? I just joined SE.

Comment: @ Sayetsu The platform informes the OP by a red sign in the StackExchange header "Recent inbox messages" about all answers or comments to his question, as well as about all other comments which are adressed to "@name". - E.g. you should have got this sign for the present comment in your StackExchange header.

Comment: Please choose a specific title with a new question, focus the new question, and avoid to expand a personal philosophy. - Did you already had a look at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help?

Comment: @Jo Wheler Just had a lookk and did a couple of searches. Didn't see anything about email notification.

Comment: ...because "untrue beliefs" would be "unimportant"/irrelevant/nonsense/waste ..."unfortunately" we have only the (personal) "horizon of experience of a human being", we won't (ever) know, how a "dog" or "electron" "feels/thinks like"...if it comes down to "believe something not-provable", i recommend: "believe it, if it makes *sense* to *you*!"

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your question about email notification [image: See the black header with the white notation]